# MPMoviePlayerController in Full Screen Mode, the done button causes the player to pause the playback

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my App, I am playing a video in a part of the screen. When I click the Fullscreen button on the player, it goes fullscreen and works fine.
But from fullscreen mode, when I click the "DONE" button to come back to previous screen, it pauses the video.

I checked the notification methods, `MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification`, `MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification`. It looks like it goes into pause mode, even before it enters the `MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification` notification method.

Any ideas how to do it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Register for `MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification` notification and unpause the video.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(handleWillExitBackgroundNotification) 
                                             MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                                           object:nil];

- (void)handleWillExitBackgroundNotification
{
    [theMovie.moviePlayer play];
    NSLog(@"Resume playback");
}
```